# Why Query Only fires OnComponentHit? It supposes to fires only Overlap events

Tags: c++, collision-detection, unreal-4

I've just started to develop with Unreal Engine 4.26.2 and I've been for five days trying to understand how collision works.

I'm developing a Pong game, and I'm trying to make that the **Ball** bounces with the **Paddle**.

The **Ball** class has a `UProjectileMovementComponent` to move it and the **Paddle** will be controlled by the player with a `UPawnMovementComponent` custom class. So, both will move.

These are my two classes:

Ball:

```
ABall::ABall()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    VisualComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("VisualComp"));
    CollisionComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("CollComp"));
    
    static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UStaticMesh> VisualAsset(TEXT("/Game/Geometry/Meshes/Ball_mesh.Ball_mesh"));

    if (VisualAsset.Succeeded())
    {
        VisualComponent->SetStaticMesh(VisualAsset.Object);
        VisualComponent->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        VisualComponent->SetWorldScale3D(FVector(1.0f));

        FBoxSphereBounds Bounds = VisualAsset.Object->ExtendedBounds;

        CollisionComponent->SetRelativeLocation(Bounds.Origin);
        CollisionComponent->SetBoxExtent(Bounds.BoxExtent);
    }

    RootComponent = CollisionComponent;
    VisualComponent->SetupAttachment(CollisionComponent);
    
    VisualComponent->SetCollisionProfileName(TEXT("NoCollision"));
    CollisionComponent->SetCollisionProfileName(TEXT("Projectile"));
    CollisionComponent->OnComponentHit.AddDynamic(this, &ABall::OnHit);

    // Use this component to drive this ball's movement.
    ProjectileMovementComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UProjectileMovementComponent>(TEXT("ProjectileMovementComponent"));
    ProjectileMovementComponent->SetUpdatedComponent(CollisionComponent);
    ProjectileMovementComponent->InitialSpeed = 0.0f;
    ProjectileMovementComponent->MaxSpeed = 90.0f;
    ProjectileMovementComponent->bRotationFollowsVelocity = false;
    ProjectileMovementComponent->bShouldBounce = true;
    ProjectileMovementComponent->Bounciness = 0.3f;
    ProjectileMovementComponent->ProjectileGravityScale = 0.0f;

}
```

Paddle:

```
APaddle::APaddle()
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // Set this pawn to be controlled by the lowest-numbered player
    AutoPossessPlayer = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;

    CollisionComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("CollComp"));
    VisualComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("VisualComp"));

    RootComponent = CollisionComponent;

    // Set up CollisionComponent as parent of VisualComponent;
    VisualComponent->SetupAttachment(CollisionComponent);
    
    VisualComponent->BodyInstance.SetCollisionProfileName("NoCollision");
    CollisionComponent->BodyInstance.SetCollisionProfileName("Pawn");

    // Initialize paddle velocity.
    CurrentVelocity.Z = 0.0f;

    // Create an instance of our movement component, and tell it to update our root component.
    OurMovementComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UPaddlePawnMovementComponent>(TEXT("CustomMovementComponent"));
    OurMovementComponent->UpdatedComponent = RootComponent;

}
```

Both classes have a `UBoxComponent` as a collision component and a `Static Mesh` as a Visual Component. The Static Mesh uses `NoCollision` Preset and Collision Component uses Pawn in the Paddle and `Projectile` (custom preset) in the Ball.

Projectile Preset is:

[image]

And Projectile Object Type is:

[image]

I have tried a lot of combinations and the only one that works is when both classes, have, at least, **Query only** selected.

I think that **Query only** is used to trigger **Overlap** events but if I don't select it, `OnComponentHit` won't trigger.

Is there anything wrong with my code or am I wrong about **Query Only** and what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kinds of questions raise little interest here.

I found the answer in the book "[Game Development Projects With Unreal Engine: Learn to Build Your First Games and Bring Your Ideas to Life Using UE4 and C ++](https://www.packtpub.com/product/game-development-projects-with-unreal-engine/9781800209220)". And the answer is:

It is correct. *Query only* is related to collision events and whether objects will bock each other's movement. So yes, I'm using the right *Collision enabled* property to block, and also it is the right *Collision enabled* property to detect overlapping also.